# Unable to follow a user in a website using some script built upon requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-re

I'm trying to follow a user in Instagram using the script below built upon requests. The script can log me in successfully but it can't help me follow that user. I tried my best to mimic the process through the script what I could see in dev tools while following that user manually.

[User](https://www.instagram.com/p/CBySO76FgD6/) that I wish to follow using the script.

This is how [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zac84.jpg) will look like when the script will work.

I've tried with:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

target_link = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CBySO76FgD6/'
profile_link = 'https://www.instagram.com/{}/'
start_link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
follow_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/{}/follow/'

username = "instagram_username"
password = "instagram_password"

timeval = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

payload = {
    'username': username,
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{timeval}:{password}',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(start_link)
    s.headers['x-csrftoken'] = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(login_url,data=payload) #it does log me in flawlessly
    # print(r.text)
    s.get(profile_link.format(username)) #send this requests only to get cookies from profile page
    r = s.get(target_link)
    follow_id = re.findall(r'viewer_can_reshare[\s\S]+?id\":\"(.*?)\"',r.text)[0]
    r = s.post(follow_url.format(follow_id),data=None)
    print(r.status_code) #giving 403 status code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make such request working you have to change some headers.
the headers should look like this:

```
'cookie': 'sessionid={}%3ADYLfeCKlCulTTJ%3A6;'.format(login_id),
'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) \
                 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
'x-csrftoken': 'rf3krAvciHRvjSBoqP4NYVXmw1wP8rEO',
'x-instagram-ajax': '846d5a59d9e9'
```

where login_id - it's id of your user. NOTE, not username, it should be numeric id (ex. 8780495634)
then you can make post request to follow ant user you want.

Comment: If you take a look at my script above, I made post requests using such numeric id. Thanks.

Comment: you use ID for user which you want to follow, but it that header I shown, it should be id of your user (under which you log it to insta)

Comment: Your solution seems to have worked out @Roman. Thanks.